# How to transform a fieldfrom a table into another table using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I'm working on this .net backend application that uses EF Code First. The `Sale` entity have this `TerminalCode` property that needs to be promoted to another entity `Terminal` because we have to keep track of it's properties now.
The EF part is done. The new entity, it's relationships and migration were created.

I have kept the old `TerminalCode` property so I can create `Terminal` entries based on it. I could create a simple console app to iterate between the `Sale.TerminalCode` property and create it's corresponding `Terminal` entries but I would rather make it part of the migration and in T-SQL. The problem is I'm not good enough with T-SQL to achieve this... In fact I don't even know if it's possible.

`Sale` entity before:

```
Id, RetailerId, TerminalCode, ...
```

`Sale` entity after:

```
Id, RetailerId, TerminalId, TerminalCode (temporary) ...
```

New `Terminal` entity:

```
Id, RetailerId, Code, ...
```

If not with some code, can someone at least point me to the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Sounds like you have a table called `Sales` with a column `TerminalCode` and a second table `Terminal`. Is that right? So what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds you have a table Sale that has a TerminalCode column, and you want to move those terminal codes to their own table and create a normalized foreign key relationship.

Here's your Retailer and Sale tables at the start:

```
CREATE TABLE Retailer (Id INT CONSTRAINT PK_Retailer PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO Retailer (Id) VALUES (1), (2), (3)

CREATE TABLE Sale (Id INT, RetailerId INT CONSTRAINT FK_Sale_RetailerId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Retailer(Id), TerminalCode VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (1, 1, 'aksjdfh')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (2, 1, 'aksjdfh')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (3, 2, 'xcvklbj')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (4, 2, 'xcvklbj')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (5, 2, 'xcvklbj')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (6, 3, '892374g')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (7, 3, '892374g')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (8, 3, '89ysasj')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (9, 3, '89ysasj')
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES (10, 3, '89ysasj')
```

Here's how you move those distinct terminal codes to their own table and create the foreign key relationships between the Terminal table and the Sale and Retailer tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Terminal (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Code VARCHAR(100), RetailerId INT)

-- If you need a constraint from Terminal to your table of Retailers, create it here, e.g.:
ALTER TABLE Terminal ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Terminal_TerminalId FOREIGN KEY (RetailerId) REFERENCES Retailer(Id)

INSERT INTO Terminal (Code, RetailerId) SELECT TerminalCode, MIN(RetailerId) FROM Sale GROUP BY TerminalCode

ALTER TABLE Sale ADD TerminalId INT CONSTRAINT FK_Sale_TerminalId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Terminal(Id)

UPDATE Sale SET TerminalId = Terminal.Id
FROM Sale
INNER JOIN Terminal ON Sale.TerminalCode = Terminal.Code

-- Drop the foreign key constraint from Sale to Retailer if one exists, e.g.:
ALTER TABLE Sale DROP FK_Sale_RetailerID

ALTER TABLE Sale
DROP COLUMN TerminalCode, COLUMN RetailerId
```

Now your schema looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Sale

Id  TerminalId
1   3
2   3
3   4
4   4
5   4
6   1
7   1
8   2
9   2
10  2

SELECT * FROM Terminal

Id  Code    RetailerId
1   892374g 3
2   89ysasj 3
3   aksjdfh 1
4   xcvklbj 2
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that Terminal also references a Retailer (because it's something like a checkout in a supermarket), so I guess I should group Sale by RetailerId and TerminalCode to move the terminal to his own table, right?

Comment: So the sale and terminal both reference a retailer?

Comment: We will probably drop the Sale's reference to a Retailer since the Terminal already references it.

Comment: Edited for your condition, but here's the thing - you shouldn't group by RetailerId and TerminalCode when creating the Terminal table. The terminal table should be a list of Terminals only. If the same Terminal can reference multiple Retailers, there should be a table TerminalRetailer between the terminal table and the retailer table.

Comment: My edit will work if you only have 1 retailer associated with each terminal. Actually, it'll still run if you have multiple retailers associated with a terminal, but it'll arbitrarily pick a retailer to assign to the terminal table.

Comment: Retailer / Terminal is a one to many relationship, but TerminalCode is only unique for a single retailer. So there are terminals from different retailers that share the same code, that's why I should group sales by TerminalCode and RetailerId.